# Recargar div o variable php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente codigo, necesito recargar el div "seccionRecargar", el problema es que al hacerlo así el código tiene que estar en otra página y yo lo que necesito es que cada x segundos se haga una consulta mysql a la base de datos para usar esa variable en esta página por lo que esta solución de cargar cada x segundos otra página no me serviría, como puedo conseguir esto?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="includes/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="seccionRecargar"></div>
    <?php
    echo rand(1,800);
    //consulta mysql
    ?>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(
                function(){
                    $('#seccionRecargar').load('seccion.php');
                },1000
            );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba algo así dentro del setInterval una peticion ajax y el sucess actualizas el div los 3 primeras propiedades son el tipo de peticion la ruta y los datos que recibes en el php.

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "",
                url: "",
                data: ,
                success: function (resp) {
                     $('#seccionRecargar').html(resp);

                }
            });
```